# Move GeoServer folder inside Jetty webapps to Tomcat webapps folder

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, jetty

Can I move the GeoServer folder app directory to the Tomcat webapps directory to migrate it to Tomcat? I do not want to update GeoServer version or do any configuration change, only migrate it to Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

The location of the app folder is not important to Tomcat, you can have it anywhere.

You just need to edit the Tomcat server.xml file to point to the location.

Tomcat on a Windows server with the GeoServer application at a location like `C:\apps\GeoServer\gs2_13-2` can be accessed by Tomcat by having the following in the server.xml file

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
     Context
        path="/gs213"
        docBase="C:\apps\GeoServer\gs2_13-2" 
        crossContext="true"
        reloadable="false"
        useRelativeRedirects="true" />
```

For a service accessed as:

```
http://localhost:8080/gs213/ows?
```